# Tmp.Node is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: electron, electron-builder, node-gyp, node-ffi

To build app for Windows on Linux CentOS 7 by using electronuserland/builder:wine image.

The packaged exe file can be installed successfully, but the application startup reports an error and the error description:

A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:Error:? C:\Users ...\AppData Loc... 26f0978b-dd24-4534-a6e6-7135af017806.tmp.node is not a valid Win32 application.? C: Users...\AppData Loc... 26f0978b-dd24-4534-ae6-7135af017806.tmp.nodeat process.func (as dlopen] (electron/is2c/asar bundle.js:5:1846)at Object.Module. extensions..node (internal/modules/cis/loader.js:1138:18)at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar bundlejs:5:2073)at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loaderjs:935:32)at Module. load (internal/modules/cis/loader.js:776:14)at Function.f. load (electron/is2c/asar bundlejs:5:12913)at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loaderjs:959:19at require (internal/modules/cis/helpers.is:88:18)at load (C:\Program Files(App\resources app.asar node modules node-gyp-build index,js:22...
at Object.canonymous>(C: Program Files\App\resources app.asar\node modules ffi-napi lib bindings.js:8:43)

Start electron app successfully

Comment: Expected starting electron app successfully.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: build app for Windows on CentOS 7 by using electronuserland/builder:wine，
error will be reported when starting.